# Getting two different results from two different approaches

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose a man has already drawn 4 spades out of 52 cards. Now, if he is given 3 additional cards, find the probability that at least one of the additional cards is also spade.

**I can approach this problem in two different ways:**

**First Way**

Cards left after drawing 4 spades = 48.
Spades left after drawing 4 spades = 9
Non-spades left = 39

So, probability that at least one of the additional cards is also spade = 1 - None of the three is spade
= $1 - \frac{39\choose 3}{48 \choose 3} = 0.4718$

**Second way**

Here, I can write:

probability that at least one of the additional cards is also spade = P(one spade in  additional 3 cards) + P(two spade in  additional 3 cards) + P(three spades in additional 3 cards) = $\frac{9\choose 1}{48 \choose 3} + \frac{9\choose 2}{48 \choose 3} + \frac{9\choose 3}{48 \choose 3}$

But this approach is not giving me the same results as the first one? Am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach's numerator should be
$$\sum_{i=1}^3 {9\choose i}{39\choose 3-i}$$
because you also need to count the number of ways to choose from the remaining cards. With your logic $0$ cards would have probability ${9\choose 0}/{48\choose 3}$, but it's not.